# PHP: Intersect two arrays and get the values of both

Tags: php, arrays, intersection

So I am a bit stuck here, I can do it with foreach loop but I want to find a cleverer way of doing it.

**Update:** There was something that I've missed in the question. The arrays may come in random order and in different length thus having different keys. Examples below updated.

Here is the case:

Array1

```
array (
    slug1 => England,
    slug2 => France,
    slug3 => Italy,
    slug4 => Germany,
)
```

Array2

```
array (
    slug2 => 215,
    slug1 => 168,
    slug4 => 55,
    slug5 => 149,
    slug3 => 40,
    slug6 => 137,
)
```

I want to intersect those arrays and build new one which has the following elements:

```
array (
    168 => England,
    215 => France,
    40 => Italy,
    55 => Germany,
)
```

**Note:** elements are not ordered though that could be achieved easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to Original Question**

You can use `array_combine` it creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

```
$array1 = array(
        "slug1" => "England",
        "slug2" => "France",
        "slug3" => "Italy",
        "slug4" => "Germany");

$array2 = array(
        "slug1" => "168",
        "slug2" => "215",
        "slug3" => "40",
        "slug4" => "55");

$final = array_combine($array2, $array1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [168] => England
    [215] => France
    [40] => Italy
    [55] => Germany
)
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/3569)

**Answer to Updated Question**

`Update: There was something that I've missed in the question. The arrays may come in random order and in different length thus having different keys. Examples below updated.`

```
$array1 = array(
        "slug1" => "England",
        "slug2" => "France",
        "slug3" => "Italy",
        "slug4" => "Germany");

$array2 = array (
        "slug2" => 215,
        "slug1" => 168,
        "slug4" => 55,
        "slug5" => 149,
        "slug3" => 40,
        "slug6" => 137);



$final = customCombine($array2, $array1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [215] => France
    [168] => England
    [55] => Germany
    [40] => Italy
)
```

Function Used

```
function customCombine($keys, $arr) {
    $t = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $k => $val ) {
        isset($arr[$k]) and $t[$val] = $arr[$k];
    }
    return $t;
}
```

Comment: An additional `ksort()` on both arrays may be needed if the order of the keys is not guaranteed to be identical.

Comment: OK that looks very good but if the arrays have different length this won't work, I know this was not mentioned but that's the curent case

Comment: @infinity that what not in your question but  ... Update your question with an example i'll update my answer with the solution

Comment: @Baba I know +1 for your answer so far it's exact match

Answer (score 2):

Baba's answer should work fine for you, but here's an interesting way to deal with different key orders between both arrays and/or different sizes.

```
// get values from $array2 in the order in which they appear in $array1
// whereby the array keys are used to match them
$keys = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
// create a new array with the keys found in the previous step and 
// another array_intersect_key() to only select the matching items
// from $array1
array_combine($keys, array_intersect_key($array1, $keys));
```

It also makes sure that `array_combine()` works with same sized arrays; the size of `$array2` is the output size.

Comment: Nice but `array_slice` would make it fail .. example  http://eval.in/3583  it returns `[215] => England , [55] => France` instead of `[55] => Germany` , [215] => France`

Comment: I think I'll need to sort both array before doing that, otherwise it'll get wrong keys/values, as @Baba pointed

Comment: `ksort` would not work .. see http://eval.in/3583 use ksort already the main issue is `array_slice` i'll update his question with the correct implementation

Comment: @Baba Fixed, the solution is kinda funky I must admit :)

Comment: @infinity As Baba mentioned, the `ksort()` won't do any good; once the arrays are of different size you're pretty much screwed :) updated my answer, it should work as expected now.

Comment: @Jack ... i was about to update your question with the answer ... lol .. nice one anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

To expand [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack)'s answer, as it might combine the arrays in the order they're constructed in and not the order the keys are matching:

```
Array
(
    [215] => England
    [168] => France
    [55] => Italy
    [40] => Germany
)
```

Some intermediate data juggling can sort it out (and it works no matter which array is shorter):

```
$array1 = array(
    'slug1' => 'England',
    'slug2' => 'France',
    'slug3' => 'Italy',
    'slug4' => 'Germany'
);

$array2 = array (
    'slug2' => 215,
    'slug1' => 168,
    'slug4' => 55,
    'slug5' => 149,
    'slug3' => 40,
    'slug6' => 137
);

$keys = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
ksort($keys);
$intersect = array_intersect_key($array1, $keys);
ksort($intersect);
$final = array_combine($keys, $intersect);

print_r($final);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [168] => England
    [215] => France
    [40] => Italy
    [55] => Germany
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_combine()`

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

https://www.php.net/array-combine

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution for me:

http://eval.in/3578

```
<?php

$array1 = array("slug1" => "England","slug2" => "France","slug3" => "Italy","slug4" => "Germany");
$array2 = array("slug1" => "168","slug2" => "215","slug3" => "40","slug4" => "55", "slug5" => "178");

ksort($array1);
ksort($array2);

$test1 = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
$test2 = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);

$final = array_combine($test2, $test1);
print_r($final);
?>
```

Comment: Should be no different than my answer. Btw, the double ksort() is not really needed here.